# why rsync is not working with crontab?

Tags: linux, centos, ssh, amazon-ec2, rsync

when I run the following manually it runs perfectly:

> /usr/bin/rsync -arvth -e "ssh -i /watch/scripts/word.pem" 1.1.1.1:/opt/ /opt

when it runs using crontab. I get:

> Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
>   rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [receiver]
>   rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(600) [receiver=3.0.6]

what am I missing here?

Thanks!
Dotan.

Comment: What command is being run from crontab?

Comment: /usr/bin/rsync -arvth -e "ssh -i /watch/scripts/word.pem" 1.1.1.1:/opt/ /opt

Comment: same command I ran manually is on the crontab

Comment: So, are you sure cron is running the script as the same user?

Comment: yes.....as root

Comment: So if you look at the sshd log on 1.1.1.1, do you see a connection using root as the user? If you add root@1.1.1.1 does it change anything? Also /watch is a complete path, or is it relative to a directory?

Comment: complete path...I'll try with root

Comment: same error even if I add root@1.1.1.1

Comment: So what do you see on the remote sshd server log?

Comment: Failed password for root from 1.1.1.1 port 49883 ssh2

Comment: Well, there you go, it's obviously not passing the .pem file correctly, did you get the same error without root@1.1.1.1 ?

Answer (score 2):

Cron does not run in the same environment (with the same environment variables) as you do in an interactive login shell. I would guess it has something todo with that.

You probably either have an ssh-agent at your local computer which you forward to get access to 1.1.1.1 or you have something else set as an environment variable that you need to access the server.

You can set environment variables for cron by setting them in the cron file:

```
VARIABLE=true
0 * * * * /usr/bin/rsync -arvth -e "ssh -i /watch/scripts/word.pem" 1.1.1.1:/opt/ /opt
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems that when you copy an AMI (Image) from one region to another on Amazon and launch an instance on the new Amazon region. the authorized_keys keeps only the certificate from the origin region although a new one was created and not the new certificate. so you have to add it manually.
Thanks,
Dotan.